# JMeter For mobile Applications testing

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

How to Configure Jmeter with Mobile devices.
In my organization we use Proxy to enable wifi on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

1. Host running JMeter and mobile devices need to be on the same subnet.
2. If your organization uses proxy for Internet access you need to "tell" JMeter to do so as well via command line arguments.

> ```
>   -H, --proxyHost <argument>
>             Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
>     -P, --proxyPort <argument>
>             Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
>     -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
>             Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>     -u, --username <argument>
>             Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
>     -a, --password <argument>
> ```

So you need to launch JMeter as follows:

```
jmeter -H {IP address or hostname of proxy server} -P {proxy server port} -u {proxy username} -a {proxy password}
```

3. Once you have this done you can point mobile devices to use JMeter's proxy rather than corporate proxy and JMeter will record mobile devices requests. See [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for end-to-end configuration steps.